# Ionic deletes lines of code in json/i18n file during deploment process

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a really strange bug in my Cordova Application.

I am using the i18n [ngx-translate plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/developer-resources/ng2-translate/). It works good. But know it is a little bit buggy. If I add a new line in the de.json or en.json file and build or run the app, the new lines will be removed. It is not possible to add new lines anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution or workaround.

I changed the folder for the language json files. You have the following code to set the root folder for the translation files.

```
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import { HttpModule, Http } from '@angular/http';
...

export function createTranslateLoader(http: Http) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}
```

But the bug still exists. It creates a backup of the i18n folder if I run the app. Really confusing.